# Parallel queueing - Multiprocessing pool, python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

My goal is to go iterate through a directory and compute the MD5 of all the files within.  I used code for a solution to a similar problem

[Parallel file matching, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623211/parallel-file-matching-python)

```
import os
import re
import sys
import time
import md5

from stat import S_ISREG

import multiprocessing

global queue
size_limit = 500000

target = sys.argv[1]



############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################
############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################
############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################
############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################
############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################
############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################
############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################
############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################
############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################
############Analysis and Multiprocessing####################

def walk_files(topdir):
     """yield up full pathname for each file in tree under topdir"""
     for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(topdir):
         for fname in filenames:
             pathname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
             yield pathname

 def files_to_search(topdir):
     """yield up full pathname for only files we want to search"""
     for fname in walk_files(topdir):
         try:
             # if it is a regular file and big enough, we want to search it
             sr = os.stat(fname)
             if S_ISREG(sr.st_mode) and sr.st_size <= size_limit:
                 yield fname
         except OSError:
             pass

def worker_search_fn(fname):
     fp = open(fname, 'rt')
     # read one line at a time from file
     contents = fp.read()
     hash = md5.md5(contents)
     global queue
     print "enqueue"
     queue.put(fname+'-'+hash.hexdigest())

################MAIN MAIN MAIN#######################
################MAIN MAIN MAIN#######################
################MAIN MAIN MAIN#######################
################MAIN MAIN MAIN#######################
################MAIN MAIN MAIN#######################

#kick of processes to md5 the files and wait till completeion

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(worker_search_fn, files_to_search(target))
pool.close()
pool.join()

#Should be done, now lets send do our analysis
while not queue.empty():
    print queue.get()
```

I added the "print enqueue" statement as a debugging purpose and I notice that the code does indeed lock up when recursing a large directory tree.  I am not sure if two processes are trying to access the queue at the same time, thus causing a deadlock.

Perhaps there is a better way to do this?  The structure does not have to be a queue but has to be lock free as to take full advantage of multiprocessing.  I want to a recurse and md5 a directory in parallel and once that is complete do something with the list as a whole.  For debugging I'm just printing the completed queue.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have already, does it fails somehow?

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear whether your program is I/O or CPU bound i.e., a single process could perform better than several processes if the task is I/O bound e.g., by minimizing number of disk seeks. You could check this by specifying different `nprocesses` values (below) and see what provides better results in your case.

You don't need queue in this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

from hashlib         import md5
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
from stat            import S_ISREG

def walk_files(topdir):
     """yield up full pathname for each file in tree under topdir"""
     for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(topdir):
         for fname in filenames:
             pathname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
             yield pathname

def files_to_process(topdir, size_limit):
    """yield up full pathname for only files we want to process"""
    for fname in walk_files(topdir):
        try: sr = os.stat(fname)
        except OSError: pass
        else:
            # if it is a regular file and small enough, we want to process it
            if S_ISREG(sr.st_mode) and sr.st_size <= size_limit:
                yield fname

def md5sum(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fp:
        # read all file at once
        contents = fp.read()
        hash = md5(contents)
        return fname, hash.hexdigest()

def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    topdir = argv[1]
    size_limit = 500000
    nprocesses = 1

    pool = Pool(processes=nprocesses)
    files = files_to_process(topdir, size_limit)
    for fname, hexdigest in pool.imap_unordered(md5sum, files):
        print("%s\t%s" % (fname, hexdigest))

if __name__=="__main__":
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

#### Example

```
$ python md5sum.py .
./md5sum.py 9db44d3117673790f1061d4b8f00e8ce
```

Answer (score 1):

Because large directory need large time to execute `walk_files()` It is not deadlock

And...

remove `pool.join()`

`multiprocessing.Pool().map()` blocks till the result is ready, so you don't need `pool.join()`