# Python multiprocessing load balancer

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Short question: Is it possible to have `N` work processes and a `balancer` process that will find worker that does nothing at this time and pass `UnitOfWork` to it?

Long question:
Imagine class like this, witch will be subclassed for certain tasks:

```
class UnitOfWork:
  def __init__(self, **some_starting_parameters):
    pass
  def init(self):
    # open connections, etc.
  def run(self):
    # do the job
```

Start the balancer and worker process:

```
balancer = LoadBalancer()
workers  = balancer.spawn_workers(10)
```

Deploy work (balancer should find a lazy worker, and pass a task to it, or else if every worker is busy, add UOW to queue and wait till free worker):

```
balancer.work(UnitOfWork(some=parameters))
# internally, find free worker, pass UOW, ouw.init() + ouw.run()
```

Is this possible (or is it crazy)?

PS I'm familiar with `multiprocessing` `Process` class, and process pools, but:

- Every `Process` instance starts a process (yep :) ) - I want fixed num of workers
- I want `Process` instance that can make generic work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any smarts in the balancer; the Queue alone will do what you want. Throw each unit of work into the queue, and have the workers loop, taking a single work unit from the queue and processing it on each iteration. I don't think there's any problem passing an instance of UnitOfWork through the queue.

If you have a fixed amount of work to be done, you can create a "no more work to be done" work unit (a "poison pill") that tells a worker to shut down, and after all the regular work is put into the queue, put as many poison pills into the queue as you have workers.

Comment: omg :) more complicated task is, the simplest answer it has :D - You just realized that I've already done something like this in another project, but I was not looking from that point of view...

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you take a look at `multiprocessing.Pool()` because I believe it exactly solves your problem.  It runs N "worker processes" and as each worker finishes a task, another task is provided.  And there is no need for "poison pills"; it is very simple.

I have always used the `.map()` method on the pool.

[Python multiprocessing.Pool: when to use apply, apply_async or map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533318/python-multiprocessing-pool-when-to-use-apply-apply-async-or-map)

EDIT: Here is an answer I wrote to another question, and I used `multiprocessing.Pool()` in my answer.

[Parallel file matching, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623211/parallel-file-matching-python/7624949#7624949)